# Designing DTOs that contain lists of objects

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, data-transfer-objects

Suppose I have the following domain models:

```
Project                Task
    - Id                   - Id
    - Name                 - Name
    - List<Task>           - Project
```

Projects have many Tasks, and Tasks have one Project.

Now suppose I want to create a TodoListDTO data transfer object. My original thought was to just do this:

```
TodoListDTO
    - List<Project>
```

Seems simple. Then I have access to the List of Tasks within each Project. Then I read in several places that DTOs should be as flat as possible. But how would I model that without using complex objects?

Instead of TodoListDTO, I could have a ProjectDTO that looks something like:

```
ProjectDTO
    - ProjectId
    - Name
    - List<TaskId>
    - List<TaskName>
```

But having separate lists of TaskIds and TaskNames seems inconvenient, and I don't see how that's any better than just having a List property on the ProjectDTO.

What's a good way to handle this?

Comment: As flat as possible does not prohibit you from modelling the problem correctly.  If a project has tasks and tasks have a single project then I don't see anything wrong with your initial design.

Comment: I would prefer the first one. Modular.. Because, if you try to access a list of projects at any point in your application, you would end up fetching all information of tasks under it. which is not efficient.

Comment: Well a *Data* **Transport** *Object* is used to transport data (f.i. import/export data to a specific JSON/XML/.. format). The models for EF are DTOs too (transport data from/to database). What is the intention for the DTOs in the question?

Comment: Prefer to keep your DTOs separate from your entity models.  I wouldn't just expose a List<Project>.

Comment: Good point. I was thinking I'd actually expose of List<ProjectDTO>, where ProjectDTO only has essential properties like Name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your previous classes were simple enough and the standard way of doing it. You would make a Context class that would keep a list of Projects and Tasks. A total of three classes.

Comment: Do you mean a Context class with two separate lists (one for Projects and one for Tasks), or a single list of Projects, each element of which has its own list of Tasks?

Comment: Yes I mean two seperate lists. However, you can omit Tasks list if your scenerio permits it. The standard way is that Context contains lists of all entity classes.

Comment: Also, As Matthew suggested, there is also a many-to-many relation between Projects and Tasks. So you can design an associative class to handle it.

Answer (score 4):

Another thing you could do is create another domain model of

```
ProjectTask
    - ProjectId
    - ProjectName
    - TaskId
    - TaskName
```

This could help with the one-to-many relationship (also allowing many-to-many) and side stepping the confusing circluar project->task->Project->task structure.  From here you can have your API client group all ProjectTasks by projectId and handle it that way.

This being said, I think your original way is fine, but here is an alternative.